# Extracting top recommendations from multiple recommendation lists

Tags: java, algorithm, list

I have four lists of recommendations and lets say the lists are A,B,C,D.
Every list has the same number of items and are represented as key-value pairs. But I need to give more priority(weights) for the elements of list A than list B, so on. Ultimately I need to select the best set of items from the four lists for the final recommendation.

Here is a use case:

List_A:
{item1,weight1}
{item2,weight1}
{item3,weight1}
{item4,weight1}
{item5,weight1}

List_B:
{item8,weight2}
{item5,weight2}
{item7,weight2}
{item2,weight2}
{item6,weight2}

List_C:
{item11,weight3}
{item23,weight3}
{item34,weight3}
{item24,weight3}
{item5,weight3}

List_D:
{item9,weight4
{item7,weight4
{item3,weight4
{item2,weight4
{item5,weight4

Suppose weight1=10, weight2=5, weight3=3, weight1=2

According to these lists the final list should have "item5" as the first item, because it exists in all four lists. How can I get the other best recommendations for these four lists?

Thanks.

Comment: Try figuring out what the final list should be and then describe all the steps you used to do so in the question.

Comment: @asThiwanka: You can upvote answers by clicking on the arrows next to them and you can accept the most helpful answers to your questions by clicking on the green checkmark. This helps organize the site and is also a way to thank the people that help you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, this should be a bit simple. On a higher level you need a data structure as

`Map<Item, Map<List, Integer>>` where the final integer is number_of_occurrences. Once you have it is straightforward to multiply number_of_occurrences * weight and throw it along with generated value in a TreeMap (a priority queue can also be used here)

Now you can have the top-n list from the TreeMap.